# Executable generated by cl runs extremely slowly the first time

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cl

When I try to compile and run simple C++ programs from the command line using the Developer Prompt for VS 2019 and VS 2017, my executables run extremely slowly the first time I run them, but are back to being fast as normal the second time onwards. Even a simple "Hello World!" program takes 10-15 seconds to finish from the time I call hello.exe the first time. It seems like there is some sort of overhead the first time I call the executable, and I'm not sure what it is. What gives?

This originally happened to me with VS 2017, so I thought it could have been a VS 2017 bug and I installed VS 2019. However, the problem persists.

For a precise example, I made a file called "test.cpp" with the following content:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    clock_t t;
    t = clock();
    std::cout << "Why is this happening?" << "\n";
    std::cout << clock() - t << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Then in the VS Developer Prompt I run "cl /EHsc test.cpp", and this finishes quickly. However, when I run "test.exe", it takes about 10-15 seconds for the output to show up. Of course the clock output is 0; there is nothing weird happening inside the main function. Also, I haven't been able to find anyone who has experienced this same issue.

Comment: Do you have any antivirus enabled?

Comment: Some AV (like aVast) with a sandbox feature will take a lot of time to execute an application the first time especially since your program is new to the AV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have antivirus enabled? If yes try with out antivirus